# how to submit newly created id into associated table/model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have two models:

```
Clients
 validates :first_name, presence: true
 validates :last_name, presence: true

 #scope :with_current_copay, joins(:insurance_providers).merge(InsuranceProvider.max.group(:client_id))

 has_many :appointments
 has_many :insurance_providers
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :insurance_providers
 belongs_to :users

end
```

and `InsuranceProviders` (which belongs_to clients).

```
class InsuranceProvider < ActiveRecord::Base
  #scope :max, -> maximum(:effective_on, :group => 'client_id') 
  belongs_to :client
end
```

I've created one form that creates a client along with an InsuranceProvider.

InsuranceProvider has a column called client_id.

The client_id doesn't exist yet when the form is being filled out. How do I put that client_id into the InsuranceProvider table?

Here is my form currently:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@client) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id  %>
    <%= f.input :first_name %>
    <%= f.input :last_name %>
    <%= f.fields_for :insurance_providers do |provider| %>
      <%= provider.input :name, label: 'Insurance provider' %>
      <%= provider.input :member_id, label: 'Member ID' %>
      <%= provider.input :copay, as: :integer %>
      <%= provider.input :effective_on, as: :date  %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

db migration:

```
class CreateInsuranceProviders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :insurance_providers do |t|
      t.integer :client_id
      t.string :name
      t.string :member_id
      t.integer :copay
      t.date :effective_on

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You don't. ActiveRecord fills in the primary keys when persisting objects to the database. Is there a specific reason why you need to set this field?

Comment: client_id is not the primary key of the insurance_providers table. It's a *foreign* key.

Comment: Yup, sorry. What I said holds true for *foreign* keys as well. So, do you think you could clarify your question?

Comment: Ok, so maybe that's not the problem. the issue i'm currently having is that I can't update _any_ field in the insurance_providers table. I'm getting a "NoMethodError" on `copay` and it points to the line `@client.save` in the `create` method of my `clients_controller.rb`.

Comment: 1) Shouldn't you be using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :insurance_providers`? 2) Can you post the entirety of your `Client` and `InsuranceProvider` models, as well as your `clients#new` and `clients#create` actions? 3) Are you absolutely sure you've created the `copay` database field? Do you have the migration for it?

Comment: 1.) lol - woops! modified but still getting the same 'copay' error. 2.) sure, one minute. 3.) absolutely positive. I'll post that, too.

Comment: i figured it out. my Clients model still had an old reference to 'copay' (i moved that column out of the clients table and into insurance_providers). that seems to have taken care of it!

Comment: I'm glad to know that you've figured it out! You can answer and accept your own question so other people will know it's been solved.

Comment: Nice, now please accept your own answer :)

Comment: not until tomorrow ;-) (SO won't allow it till then).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I originally had the 'copay' field in my Clients table (and had a reference to validating it in the model) and when I removed the column from Clients and into InsuranceProviders, I forgot to get rid of the reference in the Clients Model. This confused the hell out of both rails and myself.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you need to buid the relationships in the "new" method.

Take a look at this example:

```
  # GET /contacts/new
  # GET /contacts/new.json
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
    @contact.addresses.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @contact }
    end
  end
```

It will create a new contact and fields for a new address. This is called nested forms, so if you need to digg further.

Comment: This certainly seems like the right approach but I get a NoMethodError exception raised in the `create` method of my controller. I moved the `.build` code you provided to the `create` method instead but now but still getting the same error on `@client.save` (since the column doesn't exist on client table).